# What does "local -gA" do in Bash?

Tags: bash

```bash
...
cache_pci_init() {
    local -gA pci_bus_cache
    local -gA pci_ids_vendor
    local -gA pci_ids_device
    local -gA pci_bus_driver
    local -gA pci_mod_driver
    local -gA pci_mod_resolved
     ...
}
```

What's the meaning of `local -gA` in the Bash function shown above, especially `-gA`? When I run the program in Bash, I get the following error.

> ```
> line 43: local: -g: invalid option
> ```

Comment: Do you use `sh` or `bash`?

Comment: They appear to be using `bash` because `sh` does not support any options with `local` and just says "bad variable name" if you try to give it options.

Answer (score 4):

`local` means that the variable is defined as local to the function (so it cannot be seen by the caller). The `-gA` options are expanded to `-g -A`. The `-g` option means "Force global scope", which effectively cancels out the use of `local`. The `-A` option makes the variable an Associative Array.

So the net effect of `local -gA pci_bus_cache` is to create an Associative Array variable called `pci_bus_cache` which can be seen everywhere in the script.

You are probably getting the error because you are using an older version of `bash` that does not support the `-g` option. It is also likely that your version does not support the `-A` option.

Use the command `bash --version` to determine which version you are on.

I don't know when the `-g` option was introduced, but the `-A` option was introduced in `bash` version 4.0.

Comment: Looks like it was added in 4.2.